# Tranform a string importetd with Ajax in code to insert in an object's property method

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, object

I'm developing a **custom flexible flat windows** using an object.

In my plan, a button that calls this object need to have a peculiar class and a dedicated attribute, like this:

```
<button class="btnBox" type="button" data-use="2" version="base">Show</button>
```

Then, with an addEventListener, onClick acts a function that get the *version*, and call the `init` method of the object.

This is a simplified part of the objet itself:

```
let CustomBox = {
  btnCaller:         document.querySelector('.btnBox'),
  boxType:           'base',
  idCaller:          1,
  },
  init: function () {
    idCaller = this.idCaller;
    console.log(this.boxType);
    this.create(this.boxType);
  },
create: function (type) {
    // contiene le strutture dei layout disponibili (si potrebbero anche importare con Json)
    switch (type) {
      case 'base':
        options = {
            title: 'Test with title only',
            text: 'Look to the result!',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'OK',
                name: 'confirm',
                onClick: function () {
                  alert('Button: ' + idCaller);
                },
              },
            ],
          }
        break;

      case 'insert':
        options = {
          title: 'Search windoe',
          text: 'Insert name to search',
          inBox: 'searchName',
          buttons: [
              {
                text: 'Vai',
                name: 'search',
                onClick: function () {
                  console.log(document.getElementById('searchName').value);
                  alert('Value: ' + document.getElementById('searchName').value + 'button: ' + idCaller);
                },
              },
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                name: 'btnCancel',
              },
            ],
          }
        break;
      default:
    };
    this.call(options);
  },
template: function (opts) {
      let template = `<div class="pageCover"></div>
                      <div class="modalWindow">`;
      if (opts.title) template += `<div class="modalTitle">${opts.title}</div>`;
      if (opts.text) {
        let arr = opts.text.split('|');
        arr.forEach((item, i) => {
          template += `<p>${item}</p>`
        });
      }
      if (opts.inBox) {
        console.log(opts.inBox);
        template += `<div class="inBox">
                      <label for="${opts.inBox}"></label>
                      <input type="text" id="${opts.inBox}" name="${opts.inBox}" />
                    </div>`;
      };
      btnLength = opts.buttons.length;
      if (btnLength > 0) {
        template += `<div class="buttonArea">`;
        for (let i = 0; i < opts.buttons.length; i++) {
          template += `<BUTTON name="${opts.buttons[i].name}" btn-rif="${i}">${opts.buttons[i].text}</BUTTON>`;
        }
        template += `</div>`;
      }
      template += `</div>`;
      console.log(template);
      return template;
    },
  }
```

Well, the code isn't complete, because it's very long, but what I wrote it is enough to enucleate my problem.

Anyway, just for completeness, I can add that with the template an HTML object is created, and then through another method, the declared function is added to the click event.

Going back to my problem, I would like to make the methods more flexible. So, I created a text document (not a Json one, because the code in the functions would need too many escapes) where depending on the *version*, in case of the presence of the *inBox* property in the *buttons objects*, I take the code to put in the function of the buttons, and the HTML string to add to the template.

So, this second part is very easy, because there are only prepared strings to consider and insert, but the problem is that I should have to "transform" the strings containing the code for the functions in Js readable form, and attach that to the onClick property in the *buttons objects*.

To make it more understandable, I'll give an example: if I consider the "insert" version, I would like to load this function (it's a really easy example, the reality will be definitely more and more complex):

```
function () {alert('Value: ' + document.getElementById('searchName').value + 'button: ' + idCaller);}
```

with Ajax, and write it, as code, as the value of the 'onClick' property in the 'create' method. In the code, you can see the actual way, with a number of *cases* in a *switch* corresponding to the handled *versions*. My idea is to import these parts only for the needed *version*.

I really don't want to consider the `eval()` options. Is there someone who can give me a suggestion?